# TensorFlow Symbol Zeros is already exposed as () error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to install TensorFlow in order to install Transformers for a project, but when I run the following code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))
```

I receive this error:

```
tensorflow.python.util.tf_export.SymbolAlreadyExposedError: Symbol Zeros is already exposed as ().
```

I am trying to see the requirements for this but I have long path enabled as it would not let me download TensorFlow with it disabled. I am unable to install CUDA successfully as it shows up with a list of not installed elements that I am unsure on how to fix/install them. I am using an up-to-date version of Ubuntu and have Microsoft Visual C++, X64 architecture I think. I have also downloaded WLS2.

Comment: related?: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39606

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message. I first did `pip list`
to see all the python packages/libraries installed. I pip uninstalled all the packages with the word "keras" or "tensor" in its name.

I reinstalled tensorflow with `pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]` (on Windows), but see https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-wsl2 for Linux/Ubuntu.

Also I have never downloaded Microsoft Visual C++ or WLS2. Maybe you need to uninstall them as well.